# How do I convert original time into seconds?

Tags: c#

So I am trying to finish an assignment which involves the user to enter the original video time as a floating point value then have the user enter the playback speed
factor, again as a floating point value. Then once I have this information I will need to convert the original time into seconds then, use the factor to determine what the new video time would be. Display the results in seconds. (Note that you *must* use an integer data type to store the new video time.) Now as I already have mass majority of this code already done I'm confused on when it comes to converting part of the code.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float og_videotime, playback_speed;
        int og_videotime_seconds, new_videotime_seconds;

        Console.WriteLine("[Fast-Forward]");
        Console.Write("What is the original video time? ");
        og_videotime = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("What is the playback speed factor? ");
        playback_speed = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // convert time to seconds
        og_videotime_seconds = (int)(og_videotime * 60);
        new_videotime_seconds = (int)(og_videotime_seconds / playback_speed);

        // space
        Console.WriteLine();

        // output
        Console.WriteLine("The new video time would be {0} second(s).", new_videotime_seconds);
        Console.WriteLine("That saves you {0} second(s) from the original video speed.", og_videotime_seconds - new_videotime_seconds);
    }
}
```

A sample output provided:
[Fast-Forward]
What is the original video time? 2.30
What is the playback speed factor? 2
The new video time would be 75 second(s).
That saves you 75 second(s) from the original video speed.

Another Sample output:
[Fast-Forward]
What is the original video time? 3.59
What is the playback speed factor? 1.75
The new video time would be 136 second(s).
That saves you 103 second(s) from the original video speed.

But my code produces:
[Fast-Forward]
What is the original video time? 3.59
What is the playback speed factor? 1.75

The new video time would be 122 second(s).
That saves you 93 second(s) from the original video speed.

Math for the first sample: Now when I do the exact same number both my new video time and save seconds come out to be 69 instead of 75 which is where my confusion comes in. If I am correct to receive 75 I would have to do 2 * 60 = 120 then 120 + 30 = 150 then 150 / 2 to get 75 but I don't understand how I can break this down.

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: According to your math: 2.3*60=138; 138 / 2 = 69. Where 75 would come from?

Comment: @n0rd 75 is from the sample output which is supposed to be my output when I use the input numbers 2.30 and 2

Comment: Can you show the math that would get you from 2.3 to 75?

Comment: @n0rd I wish I could the assignment just gives me the numbers and what my output is supposed to be and if it doesnt match the system considers the whole code wrong itself.

Comment: What does 2.30 mean? 2 + 30/100 minutes, or 2 minutes and 30 seconds (half of which *is* 75 seconds)?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing 2.30 means 2 mins and 30 seconds

Comment: So don't just multiply by 60 but treat the "2" and ". 30" separately

Comment: Why are you using `float` and not the default `double`? Trying to save precious stack space?

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote looks like C. Predefining variables? Why?

I don't know why, but nobody is suggesting to use the `TimeSpan` class. It has support for arithmetic. It has a `Parse` method. It actually represents a timespan. It can output in seconds

You just have to feed it a correct time format. "hh:mm:ss"

```cs
Console.Write("What is the original video time? ");
var og_videotime = TimeSpan.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("What is the playback speed factor? ");
var playback_speed = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var new_videotime = og_videotime / playback_speed;
Console.WriteLine($"The new video time would be {new_videotime.TotalSeconds:0.00} second(s).");
```

edit: IMHO using `float` would *not* be a C# way to go. But there are plenty bad professors around, so you might be stuck with learning to program the wrong way.

Comment: Timespans are clunky for user to enter and are a source of errors. What "2:30" parses into? 2 minutes 30 seconds? 2 hours 30 minutes? Why?

Comment: @n0rd you seem biased. `TimeSpan` is the C# standardized way to represent a -wait for it- time span. I'm not complete, because `TimeSpan.Parse` actually uses the localized representation of the time format. _And those are standardized._ Furthermore, the documentation clearly explains what `Parse` will do, and they will not change that.

Comment: @n0rd it is commonly known that _every_ user input is a source of errors. Take all the other answers for instance: _"What is the original video time? "_: _"Three hours, five minutes and forty seconds"_... Will also throw an exception. Input requirements and checking user input are part of designing and writing business logic. Why would entering "2.30" represent 2 hours and some minutes? How many minutes is not even clear from that value. The user has to use a calculator to convert the hour-minutes-seconds specified on the movie box to a fractional number.

Comment: @n0rd I'm just saying that if you're in a technical interview for a senior C# programmer position and you're asked to do such an assignment and start doing stuff like string parsing of  `float` numbers, you're not going to get the job.

Answer (score 0):

just edit this line:
You are `multiplying 2.30 by 60` and the `result is 138`. Not 150

```
  // og_videotime_seconds = (int)(og_videotime * 60);
   var temp = og_videotime.ToString("N2").Split('.');
   og_videotime_seconds = int.Parse(temp[0]) * 60 + int.Parse(temp[1]);
```

You can multiply the `number part of og_videotime` by `60` and `add it to the decimal part`.

Comment: If you are going to convert a number to a string, why not just read it as a string from the start?

Comment: @n0rd Yes, you can read as string from the beginning. I wanted to edit just one line of your code...

Comment: @Hossein if you don't mind, could you explain what you typed down.. I'm sorry I'm very new to this, also I dont think I can read it as a string from the beginning since the instruction want me to prompt it as a floating point value. then again i'm very new to this and I am probably wrong

Comment: @maailpreston You just move the code I posted and your program will be fixed without any changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:
I just made a small change

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float og_videotime, playback_speed;
        int og_videotime_seconds, new_videotime_seconds;

        Console.WriteLine("[Fast-Forward]");
        Console.Write("What is the original video time? ");
        og_videotime = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("What is the playback speed factor? ");
        playback_speed = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // convert time to seconds
        var FloatToMin =og_videotime.ToString().Split('.');
        og_videotime_seconds = (int.Parse(FloatToMin[0]) * 60) + int.Parse(FloatToMin[1]);
        new_videotime_seconds = (int)(og_videotime_seconds / playback_speed);

        // space
        Console.WriteLine();

        // output
        Console.WriteLine("The new video time would be {0} second(s).", new_videotime_seconds);
        Console.WriteLine("That saves you {0} second(s) from the original video speed.", og_videotime_seconds - new_videotime_seconds);
    }
}
```

My mother says: the mountain that can be seen is not far away, don't stop trying

Comment: @maailpreston To perform calculations, you need and must change the types

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To go from a float value of 2.3 to 150 seconds, *without* extra string manipulation inbetween:

```cs
float og_videotime = 2.30f; // result of the "float.Parse"

int mins = (int)Math.Floor(og_videotime); // 2 [minutes]
int secpart = (int)Math.Round((og_videotime - mins) * 100); // 2.3 - 2 = 0.3; 0.3 * 100 = 30 [seconds]
int og_videotime_seconds  = secpart + mins * 60; // 150 [seconds]
```